# How can Tenant database connect to the core database

Tags: sql-server, multi-tenant

I have a Multi-Tenant databases.
The shared database have the tenants config table that holds all the tenants info

each of the tenants databases has an insertion trigger, that inserts a new record to the core database attaching the tenant id to that record.

i need to know from which tenant database the insertion came, to be able to set the tenant id based on the database that did the process.

is there a unique id related to each database that i can depend on ?! ..

Comment: Could you please share why would you create a new record in core db for each tenant specific record? When you know the entity to which you are inserting the data, you should be obviously knowing about the tenant from the context

Comment: Actually it is a SQL trigger, that is fired if a new record added to a table that is needed to be only in the tenant databases

When this trigger fired, i need to add a new record to the core DB (a task table to be handled later), and this task stores the tenant id to be able to understand from which tenant this task came, and where shall it process it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL2008 or higher you can use either [DB_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-id-transact-sql) or [DB_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-name-transact-sql) to identify the database:

```
SELECT DB_ID() "Id", DB_NAME() "Name"
```

If you used `DB_ID` and want to display the database name for your reports you can use:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(3) -- i.e. DB_NAME(DB_ID())
```

Comment: If you want to display the full list -  `SELECT name "Name", database_id "Id" FROM sys.databases`